# How can index.html be created/updated automatically?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, html, sftp

I have a (sub)domain on a shared hosting service with a structure like that below which I control via `sftp` from a Linux platform. The `index.html`s don't exist yet and I want to create them automatically to look very plain, similar to [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/). Automatically means that every time I add a new file into the `Dir`ectories, the `index.html`s should be updated automatically, or created at the time the user acesses the site. When the user clicks on a link of the `index.html`, the should see the linked html site.

```
'--Subdomain_a
  '--httpdocs
    '--.htaccess
    '--index.html
    '--Dir1
      '--index.html
      '--file1.html
      '--file2.html
    '--Dir2
      '--index.html
      '--file1.html
      '--file2.html
```

I believe that should be possible without much effort or additional software. A websearch result suggested to add `Options +Indexes` line to my `.htaccess` file:

```
Deny from All
Allow from 123.456.789.10
Options +Indexes
```

However, that didn't create the `index.html`s.

My problem is that I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for. I just remember in the early days of the internet, a lot of websites looked plain as my linked example, and I believe this therefore might be a default index file generated by the apache (?) server or such sort of thing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you linked to indeed uses automatic directory indexing of the Apache httpd. That's the classic icon set that comes with Apache, but many other web servers also have (usually even plainer) indexing.

However, it is not a file. Directory indexing *does not create* any actual index.html files – instead, Apache just generates the page *on the fly,* every time someone makes the HTTP request, so even when it works you'll never see an index.html show up via SFTP. (It's like CGI or WSGI apps in that regard.)

Usually `Options +Indexes` should be enough to enable this. But you're not seeing the automatic index *via HTTP*, then it's actually possible that your web host disabled AllowOverrides for users, or in fact didn't even load the 'mod_autoindex' module – those are not something you can fix via .htaccess; it has to be done by the host.

An alternative is to use a PHP page to generate such an index (most shared hosts support PHP), then you can use 'DirectoryIndex' to make httpd use that page as the default "index file" for *all* directories without needing to manually copy it there. The PHP script will be told which location it's being served for, and can generate a list of files accordingly. (There are a few such programs that build *very* fancy indexes, but in your case I'd just start from scratch.)