# How to enable apache directory listing on DSM6?

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, nas, htaccess

I want an index to be automatically generated, very similar to the example below. For my website on the internet my web host configured Apache properly, now I need to do this for our intranet on a Synology NAS.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1649032/788591) I put `Options +Indexes` into a `.htaccess` file, but it doesn't work yet. A web search pointed me to add `AllowOverride All` to the Apache configuration, which I attempted to do in the `/usr/local/etc/apache24/conf/httpd24.conf` file I found (see config file in edit below). However, the entry already exists in line 76:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

For testing purposes, the respective directory, contains the old (renamed) `_index.html` file and a `foo.html` and can be reached e.g. using e.g. `192.168.1.2/index.html`:

```
$ ls /volume1/web/
@eaDir  foo.html  _index.html
```

The `foo.html` should be listed just as in the picture below.

Currently i get 404 with `http://192.168.1.2/index.html` and 500 with `http://192.168.1.2/` respectively. `http://192.168.1.2/foo.html` shows me my website.

So, it seems that I'm stuck and don't know, how to proceed further. Any ideas?

*Example:*

[image]

**Note:** I'm running `DSM 6.2.4-25556` with the linux `4.4.59+ x86_64` kernel and `Apache 2.4` running.

---

### Edit

Here is the original Apache configuration file as is (unchanged):

```
$ cat httpd24.conf 

ServerRoot "/usr/local/etc/apache24"

Listen 127.0.0.1:915

LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User http
    Group http
</IfModule>

ErrorLog /run/apache24-error_log
TraceEnable off
LogLevel error

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%{X-Real-IP}i  %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%{X-Real-IP}i  %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%{X-Real-IP}i  %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog /dev/null combined
    #CustomLog /run/apache24-access_log combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    ScriptSock /run/httpd/user-cgisock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddEncoding x-compress Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip gz tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</IfModule>

MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
EnableMMAP off

# TODO: AllowOverride of root directory to All ??
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# TODO: should apache handle this or nginx?
<IfModule deflate_module>
    DeflateCompressionLevel 2
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.[0678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s7  !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

# TODO: should apache handle this or nginx
<Files ~ "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
</Files>

<VirtualHost _default_:80 _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/services/web"
    Alias /_webstation_/ "/var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/"
</VirtualHost>

# TODO: Should apapche handle FileETag
# For CVE-2003-1418
FileETag MTime Size

Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Include conf/extra/mod_xsendfile.conf
Include conf/extra/mod_rpaf.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Contents of `sites-enabled`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/etc/apache24/sites-enabled
httpd-vhost.conf  webstation-default.conf

$ cat /usr/local/etc/apache24/sites-enabled/httpd-vhost.conf 
Alias /_webstation_/ "/var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/"
ErrorDocument 400 /_webstation_/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /_webstation_/401.html
ErrorDocument 402 /_webstation_/402.html
ErrorDocument 403 /_webstation_/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /_webstation_/404.html
ErrorDocument 405 /_webstation_/405.html
ErrorDocument 406 /_webstation_/406.html
ErrorDocument 407 /_webstation_/407.html
ErrorDocument 408 /_webstation_/408.html
ErrorDocument 500 /_webstation_/500.html
ErrorDocument 501 /_webstation_/501.html
ErrorDocument 502 /_webstation_/502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /_webstation_/503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /_webstation_/504.html
ErrorDocument 505 /_webstation_/505.html

$ cat /usr/local/etc/apache24/sites-enabled/webstation-default.conf 
<Directory "/var/services/web">
    <FilesMatch "\.(php[345]?|phtml)$">

        Redirect 500
    </FilesMatch>
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.cgi index.php index.php5
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

A `<Directory>` section [typically takes a directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory). So you may want to try e.g.:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/httpd/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

---

*Additional Comments*

Please forgive me if I go over anything you already know. =)

- `<Directory>` sections are often applied under a corresponding `<VirtualHost>`. So, for instance, to apply one to the root of your default `<VirtualHost>`, you might use:

  ```
  <VirtualHost _default_:80 _default_:443>

        DocumentRoot "/var/services/web"
        Alias /_webstation_/ "/var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/"

        <Directory "/var/services/web">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- You likely shouldn't what's suggested above. Instead, verify `sites-enabled` contains (most likely) symlinks to e.g. `sites-available` and some file(s) underneath that. Then try updating whichever virtual host is relevant under ex. `sites-available`.
- Assuming `/volume1/web/` is actually where the files you want to index live, there probably should be no trailing slash (e.g. you likely want to use `/volume1/web`).
- I'm not sure what DSM is based off of, but it is common for distros that use `sites-enabled/sites-available` to require
  something like e.g. `sudo a2ensite some.conf` when adding a virtual host `.conf` file. That said, I would suspect that this wouldn't apply to merely updating an existing file.
- After any updates, you do need to restart Apache (e.g. something like `sudo systemctl restart apache2`).

Comment: I tried to add `/volume1/web/` as the directory, without success, though. Please see my updated question, I added some more details, thanks.

Comment: Extended my answer to address your updated information.

Comment: Thanks for update, still couldn't figure it out. I added Contents of `sites-enabled`, hope this helps.

Comment: I came across a similar issue in DSM. The problem is that the root level <Directory> directive in the synology apache2.conf doesn't apply to any VirtualHosts for some reason. I don't fully understand why. But putting a Directory directive inside the VirtualHost as per your answer seems to work fine. Also it must be the original directory, i.e. /var/services/web, not the /volume1/web symlink target.